# Kill process after execute command in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to kill process (or exit them) after my commands will complete. I have this code, but process exits immediately.

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.list({
    category: gplay.category.GAME_ACTION,
    collection: gplay.collection.TOP_FREE,
    start: 0,
    num: 120
  })
  .then(console.log, console.log);

gplay.list({
    category: gplay.category.GAME_ACTION,
    collection: gplay.collection.TOP_FREE,
    start: 120,
    num: 120
  })
  .then(console.log, console.log);
process.exit();
```

I run this by `node script.js > output.txt`, because i want to write output to file. I don't know other method.

Comment: Just delete the process.exit() line, it should exit automatically once both calls are completed. Also, you can use fs to write to the file automatically instead of logging to console (up to you really, depends on the scope of the project and reusability requirements)

Comment: your process exits because of the `process.exit()` sentence. Just remove it and your process will finish when all the pending calls are done.

Comment: @JonLuca i don't know how to use writing instead of logging to console

Comment: @PA.when i removed process.exit() my RAM increased to 4-5GB

Comment: The process "hangs in the air"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all`

> It returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

The callback `displayThenExit` will display the results then exits the node process

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

var p1 = gplay.list({
    category: gplay.category.GAME_ACTION,
    collection: gplay.collection.TOP_FREE,
    start: 0,
    num: 2
  })  

var p2 = gplay.list({
    category: gplay.category.GAME_ACTION,
    collection: gplay.collection.TOP_FREE,
    start: 2,
    num: 2
  })  
var displayThenExit = function(result){
    console.log(result);
    process.exit(0);
}

Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(displayThenExit, console.log);
```

*ps:* I set `num: 2` to limit the number of entries returned for testing purpose

Comment: Thanks for your help @taha! It works but what can I do, when i have p1...p36 variables?

Comment: @J.Doe: most likely you're hitting Google Play's throttling limit. https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper#throttling

Comment: Can i set custom delay for requests?

Comment: Check the link, they gave a solution to this issue (`throttle` property)

Comment: There is no throttle, because it works for p1...p5 variables now. If I increase it for p1...p6, it didn't work.

Comment: @J.Doe: I'm not sure how can I help you get the results you want. But as far as I know there is a queries limit per day

Comment: I try Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]) at the moment and it works so I think that i haven't reached daily limit yet. When I try Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6]) then i have empty console.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is highly asynchronous in nature that means after invoking the first function call it will immediately move to the next statement. In your case there are two possible ways:

1. Either put the next line of execution inside the then() of the first one and put exit() inside the then() block of second call.
2. Use async https://caolan.github.io/async/
3. Or simply remove exit();

Comment: The process "hangs in the air" when i removed process.exit()

Comment: In that case either 1 or 2 should work. I will use the 2nd one